# ServiceStack Caching Working in VS2012, but not in Xamarin Studio 4.2.3 (build 60)

Tags: caching, visual-studio-2012, servicestack, xamarin-studio, servicestack-razor

My application makes an AJAX call to the route /{Lang}/cook to retrieve an rendered Razor partial.

In VS2012 via Cassini, I am able to get a response;

However, in Xamarin 4.2.3 (build 60), I get the following error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (NotImplementedException)

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/en-us/cook
```

Any ideas why the route works in one IDE, but not the other?

I am using Service Stack **4.0.12.0**, with In-Memory caching.
The system is being run in free/evaluation mode.

Here is a service method that uses caching:

Inside public class **ScenarioService: Service**

```
[DefaultView("cook")]
public object Get(CookScenario request)
{
    var cacheKey = GetCacheKey ("cook", request.Lang);

    return base.Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache (base.Cache, cacheKey, () => {
        CookScenarioResponse response = LoadJson<CookScenarioResponse>(request.Lang, "cook");
        return response;
    });
}
```

Inside **AppHost.cs**

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    //Set JSON web services to return idiomatic JSON camelCase properties
    ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

    //Configure User Defined REST Paths

    container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

    this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((request, response, requestDto) =>
    {

         var localizedReq = requestDto as LocalizedRequest;
         if (localizedReq != null)
         {
             Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(localizedReq.Lang);
         }

    });
    Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());

}
```

**EDIT:** 
I tried removing the ToOptimizedResultUsingCaching and the service for "/en-us/cook" worked fine; so, the issue is definitely an issue with the ToOptimizedResultUsingCaching in Service Stack 4.0.12.0 on Xamarin Studio 4.2.3 (build 60) on a Mac OS 10.7.5.

Here is the mono version info:
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.6 ((no/9b58377 Thu Jan 16 17:49:56 EST 2014)

**Resolution 3/27/2014 1PM PST**

After I grabbed the pre-release version (4.0.16) of ServiceStack I was able to confirm that in-memory caching now works on Xamarin 4.2.3 (build 60) against my Macbook pro laptop (OSX 10.7.5).

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error you are seeing is a shortcoming of Mono, and the XSP/fastcgi-server-4 host which is used by Xamarin Studio.

I previously experience the same problem with `ToOptimizedResult`/`ToOptimizedResultUsingCache` methods not working because they rely on a call to `System.Web.HttpContextWrapper.GetService` which has not been implemented in Mono.

[See here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web.Abstractions/System.Web/HttpContextWrapper.cs#L187) for the relevant Mono source code:

```cs
public class HttpContextWrapper : HttpContextBase
{
    ...

    [MonoTODO]
    public override object GetService (Type serviceType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
```

I found the only way to work around this issue with Mono was to use a Self Hosted ServiceStack application because it uses `System.Net.HttpListener` which does not suffer from this issue. [See my previous answer on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21294048/1295344) which describes this in more detail.

---

### Fix:

[A commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/1f648eb474d972bf5f09f49dc3a4fad8fc07b2e8) to ServiceStack has been made to address this issue, and it will be fixed in version 4.0.16

Comment: Wow, this is great. Yes, I tried running the project on Xamarin Studio on my MacBook Pro. I couldn't put my finger on why ToOptimizedResultUsingCache was only working on my Windows 7 laptop running Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Is there a way to use caching without going through ToOptimizedResultUsingCache in ServiceStack 4? My company has a commercial license and they are a Mac shop. However, we deploy the code from Jenkins running on Windows to Azure Cloud Services.

Comment: @Abe I have looked into it, and I think we can get this issue resolved. I am submitting a patch to ServiceStack, in the meantime I did put a solution to work around `ToOptimizedResult`.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I also raised the issue to @ServiceStack and Demis has posted an updated at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/1f648eb474d972bf5f09f49dc3a4fad8fc07b2e8

Comment: @Abe The issue should now be addressed in the next build of ServiceStack. As a [commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/1f648eb474d972bf5f09f49dc3a4fad8fc07b2e8) has been made to prevent the exception.

Comment: Scott, thank you so much for your help; it definitely saved at least a month's worth of work.